# Sentry can not synchronize the ACLs between HDFS files and Hive tables

Tags: java, hdfs, thrift, apache-sentry

Sentry cannot send a full image snapshot of Hive table access control list to HDFS, so that HDFS ACL and Hive table ACL are not synchronized.

I am running Cloudera CDH 5.14.2, which contains Sentry 1.5.1 and Hadoop 2.6.0.
I have enabled Sentry and ACL synchronization with HDFS.

Recently we restart cluster in order to refresh some configurations in HDFS log4j, however, after the system is back, we found the ACL between Hive table and HDFS file are not synchronized.

We then rollback the log4j config and restart the cluster again, however, the acls are still not synchronized between Hive table and HDFS file.

After some investigations, we find it may be caused by a large number of partitions and tables in Hive (indeed, we have millions of tables and partitions in Hive) according to sentry-2183. So we change the configuration `sentry.hdfs.service.client.server.rpc-connection-timeout` to 1800000 in the `hive-site.xml` file of the metastore server, however, it does not work.

We noticed that there are warning and error messages in Sentry and HDFS log.
In Sentry log, it shows an warning about:

> "WARN org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport: Error closing
>   output stream. java.net.SocketException: Socket closed"

In HDFS, it shows an error:

> "ERROR
>   orgapache.sentry.core.common.transport.RetryClientInvocationHandler:
>   failed to execute getAllUpdateFrom
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException", which is caused by
>   "org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutExcpetion: Read time out"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mifq6.png)

Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

We have rather big hadoop cluster and faced with just the same issue. 
In our case we rebuild Postgres index for the sentry DB and this helps.

```
CREATE INDEX "AUTHZ_PATH_FK_IDX" ON "AUTHZ_PATH" USING btree ("AUTHZ_OBJ_ID");
```

According to Cloudera manuals:
Oracle:

```
CREATE INDEX "AUTHZ_PATH_FK_IDX" ON "AUTHZ_PATH" ("AUTHZ_OBJ_ID");
```

Apache Derby:

```
CREATE INDEX AUTHZ_PATH_FK_IDX ON AUTHZ_PATH (AUTHZ_OBJ_ID);
```

IBM Db2:

```
CREATE INDEX AUTHZ_PATH_FK_IDX ON AUTHZ_PATH (AUTHZ_OBJ_ID);
```

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/cdh_rn_sentry_ki.html

Comment: Do not answer, if you haven't an answer.